# How to delete a specific commit in git?

Tags: git, version-control

We are using git in a project having team size of six people. One accidentally do a wrong commit but realised after doing some more useful commits.

Is it possible to delete that particular commit in git?

Comment: Before reading the related questions, please find out if that user **pushed their commit to the central repository or not**. It is really important.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `revert`:

```
git revert #commithash
```

Comment: Maybe a good idea to inform question author that `revert` does not actually delete a commit, but creates a new one which completely invert the original